# Clonezilla doesn't show OpenStack option to save image

Tags: clonezilla

The official Clonezilla documentation (https://www.partclone.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) says: «There are other options, e.g. sshfs, samba, nfs or webdav, AWS S3 or Openstack Swift, you can use when network is available.»

In a discussion (https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Clonezilla_live/thread/a3fac2ff/), we can read: «you can use Amazon S3, OpenStack Swift, or Google cloud storage with Clonezilla live. So far we only put the former two in Clonezilla live menu.»

I downloaded the "alternative stable - 20220103-impish":
https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php

My issue is that Clonezilla doesn't show any OpenStack option where to save the image:
[image]

Comment: Since OpenStack Swift is S3 compatible I would assume that you could select "s3_server" and continue, have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation: on Stable Clonezilla live 2.6.5-21 (2020-03-10) the "OpenStack Swift" option was removed from the menu, as they said on their [changelog](https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/news/2020/03/stable-clonezilla-live-265-21-released/).

> Remove archivemount and cloudfuse from packages list of clonezilla live since: (1) It requires fuse v2 but now only fuse v3 is available in Debian Sid. (2) It's not maintained for many years. (3) It's not used basically. **The swift repository is temporarily removed from prep-ocsroot dialog menu.**

But you may still be able to use it:

> Add s3ql in the packages list so that **user can manually mount swift/S3 cloud storage**.